# Actions must be plain objects error using Redux Thunk

Tags: reactjs, redux, async-await, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am encountering the following error while using redux-thunk. I am stuck for days and I have found many answers regarding on this question in stack overflow but none of them help. Sorry this maybe a stupid question. Any helps would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much

Error I am facing:
***Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.***

Store.js:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk'
import reducer from './reducers'

const store = createStore(reducer, {}, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk))
export default store
```

my Action:

```
export const getAllClientList = () => async (dispatch) => {
 try {
  let clientList = await axios.get(API_URL)
    dispatch({ type: types.RECEIVE_CLIENTLIST, clientList })
  } catch (e) {
    dispatch({ type: types.ERROR, message: e.message })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think the action creators must be a sync action. However if you need to dispatch and action with async logic you must use some middleware like redux-thunk or redux-promise-middleware. Using the later you can create your action like

```
const getAllClientList = () => ({
  type: types.RECEIVE_CLIENTLIST,
  payload: axios.get(API_URL).then(() => {....}),
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to assign clientList to a property of the action? 
For instance a payload one:

{ type: types.RECEIVE_CLIENTLIST, payload:clientList }

Comment: Hello, phil. Thank you for your comment. I have tried to assign to the property clientList of the action and in my reducer I take the propery as action.clientList. Sigh. I feel really desperate after being stuck for daysss. :(

Comment: This doesn't pinpoint what is wrong with your code (probably need to see more), but I created a version that seemed to work in codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/kmq07z6o1r

Comment: hi phil. How is your day going? Just want to keep you update on my issue~ I found the bug has nothing to do with redux-thunk. It was caused by the front-end framework i am using (because of some reasons the redux-thunk did not apply on the store). Thank you for your help anyway. Wish you all the best :) !!

Comment: Hi Fredmo. Thanks a lot for your update and glad you found a solution.!